# MongoDB reference in validation schema

Tags: mongodb, database-design

Is there a way in mongodb to reference an element to another in the same document in schema validation? In JSON schema $ref is not supported so what's the alternative? Is there any workaround? Thank anyone for help. Here is an example:

```
{ 
  a : [1, 4, 9, 10]
  b : 1
}
```

In this case, what we want is to ensure that the value of "b" is in the array "a" in order not to have something like { b : 5 },
which value 5 is not in the "a" array. Thank anyone for help

Answer (score 0):

can't you map through a and check if b equals an index of a else error

Comment: Hello. How can I do that? I have already tried using both JSONschema and mongodb $ operators but I've found no way to compare a value to something that is not static. Can you tell me please? Thank you

Comment: Hello I'm not sure how to do it in mongo you can always check for this when you add b or update b attributes or when creating this attribute  to do this ```     const users = User. find() ; users.map((user)=>{var {a, b} =user ; for(var i=0;i<b.length;i++){if(a==b[i]) break;} if(i==b.length)//b isn't in a})